# Big query external connection to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, google-bigquery

I'm using Big query to query S3 storage.
As you know I can add an external table from S3.
So I clicked add table => selected S3 source => filled the right URL => filled the ARN role
but I got an error so I looked at the helping icon and the requested format is fit to what I did.
What is the problem? Does someone face the same issue?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are using an IAM User instead of an IAM Role.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bruno said, you are using an `IAM User` instead of an `IAM Role`. So, change your `AWS role id` input from:

```
arn:aws:iam::account:user/user-name
```

To below ARN format to resolve your issue:

```
arn:aws:iam::account:role/my-role
```